# How to check if row is unique in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I am working on a PowerBI where I have to compare two rows to check and assign 1 to one of the value and 0 to rest.

For example -

Data is like this:

```
Employee ID
    097647231  
    030300558     
    097647231
    040114563      
    097647231              
    040114563
    030300558
```

I want something like this:

```
Employee ID  1/0 
030300558     1
030300558     0
097647231     1
097647231     0
097647231     0
040114563     1 
040114563     0
```

The file is very big (almost 90,000 rows) and comparing based on index takes a very long time. What are the other ways in power query editor to achieve this efficiently.
I am doing this - "if [Index] = 0 then 1 else if [#"Employee ID"] = #"Added Index"[#"Employee ID"]{[Index]-1} then 0 else 1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to group on EmployeeID and add index to the groups

Then when you expand, each EmployeeID will be consecutively numbered.

Anything with a 1 should stay a 1, and anything else should become a zero, which you can do with a transform operation

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
Group = Table.Group(Source, {"Employee ID"}, {{"GRP", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 1, 1), type table}}),
#"Expanded GRP" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Group, "GRP", {"Index"}, {"Index"}),
#"Transform" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Expanded GRP",{{"Index", each if _ =1 then 1 else 0, type number}})
in #"Transform"
```